# How does Gmail calculate the size of a message which contains an attachment?

Tags: gmail, gmail-attachments

I am getting rejection on my 13.5MB attachment even though size limit is 15MB. So, I want to know the exact policy by Gmail, as in how do they calculate the size of an email which contains attachment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 15MB limit is for the entire message, not just attachments.

To check the size of a message, open it, and select Show Original from the menu in the upper right. This opens the entire message in a new tab/window. Save this to a plain text file and the size of that file is the total size of the message.

Tl;dr: If Gmail says your message is too big, you'll have to make it smaller. Try sharing the file via Drive or Dropbox and emailing a link.

Comment: That was helpful, thank you. I also got some info from other sources. Got answers like gmail uses Base64 encoding which automatically adds its own data. You should always keep the buffer of 33% to ensure guaranteed delivery.